# Compare values on sheet with whole worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Multiple edits later:

I have an excel spreadsheet with several sheets, 4 to 8, are information from previous reports. And I have sheet NIKE which contains all updated values, among those rows are current items and new items, I have made my way for a code that could read NIKE's rows and see if any row is new on sheets 4 to 8.

Sadly I'm having a code that works partially ok, meaning that the code reads and is able to copy some of the needed rows.

Please see code below

```
Sub CompareNew()
Dim cellName, cellCl As Range
Dim uF, uFS As Long
Dim sName, ClName As String
Dim sDevice, sImported, sTracker As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sImported = Sheets("NIKE-DOC-REP-DEVICE_SERVICETOCI")
uF = sImported.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set sTracker = Sheets("Tracking Add-Delete") 'Hoja de tracking
uFT = sTracker.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cellName In sImported.Range("A2:A" & uF)
sName = cellName
ClName = cellName.Offset(, 3)

Set sDevice = Worksheets(sName)
uFS = sDevice.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set cl = sDevice.Range("E5:E" & uFS).Find(ClName, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
    If cl Is Nothing Then
        sDevice.Cells(uFS + 1, 2) = sDevice.Cells(uFS, 2) + 1
        sImported.Activate
        sImported.Range(Cells(cellName.Row, 2), Cells(cellName.Row, 10)).Copy sDevice.Cells(uFS + 1, 3)
        sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 2) = Format(Date, "[$-en-US]mmmm d, yyyy;@)") 'El codigo ya empieza a copiar informacion a la hoja de Tracking
        sImported.Cells(cellName.Row, 4).Copy sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 3)
        sImported.Cells(cellName.Row, 2).Copy sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 4)
        sImported.Cells(cellName.Row, 3).Copy sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 5)
        sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 6) = "Added"
    Else
    End If
Next cellName

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This code will read the rows being added from NIKE towards the rest of the workbook and add them if not present, afterwards I will copy them to the tracker sheet (Currently adding all to their respective sheet but not copying'em all to the tracker sheet)

And below is the opposite code..

```
Sub CompareOld()
Dim cellName, cellCl As Range
Dim uF, uFS As Long
Dim sName, ClName As String
Dim sDevice, sImported, sTracker As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wsName = Array("WAN Backbone-DC-RoutersSwitches", "Tools Servers", "Backbone Firewall", "Voice Messaging Managed Device", "NGWAN devices")

For i = 0 To UBound(wsName)
    Set sDevice = Worksheets(wsName(i))
    uFS = sDevice.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set sImported = Sheets("NIKE-DOC-REP-DEVICE_SERVICETOCI")
    uF = sImported.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set sTracker = Sheets("Tracking Add-Delete")
    uFT = sTracker.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cellName In sDevice.Range("E5:E" & uFS)
        ClName = cellName

        Set cl = sImported.Range("E5:E" & uFS).Find(ClName, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
        If cl Is Nothing Then
            sTracker.Activate
            sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 2) = Format(Date, "[$-en-US]mmmm d, yyyy;@)")
            sDevice.Cells(cellName.Row, 5).Copy sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 3)
            sDevice.Cells(cellName.Row, 3).Copy sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 4)
            sDevice.Cells(cellName.Row, 4).Copy sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 5)
            sTracker.Cells(uFT + 1, 6) = "Removed"
            sDevice.Rows(cellName.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cellName
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This one will do it backwards, comparing the currently existing rows and if any of them is not present in NIKE sheet will remove it from its current sheet and copy to the tracker sheet. (This is almost not working at all... dunno why!)

Attached is the file, please refer to VBA Module2 which contains this I'm trouble with.

File below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10rXA6fInX5g8zJucrnxsNHl-7vXBpIvz/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for any tip! And as always, sorry for the trouble...

Comment: With some help got the answer to the CompareNew and CompareOld. Now its time to fix the tracker updater.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Set lookIn = Sheets(strName).Range("E5:B" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

...you could try...

```
Set lookIn = Sheets(strName).Range*"E5:B" & !Sheets(strName).UsedRange.Rows.Count - x
```

...where `x` is the number of rows from the bottom to skip.  Might be a good idea at least for the last sheet if that's the only one that's a problem.

(That code is untested since I don't know anything about your data so you might have to tweak it sightly.)

Some people will tell you that `UsedRange` isn't a good way to loop through  a range, since if you put data in a cell, then erase the data from that cell, it's still considered "Used".

But I've never had an issue with it, and it's quicker than some alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helps on selecting the right sheet however its still causing issues 

The rawName sheet contains 2k rows, which contains devices that are or will be stored in the other 5 different sheets.
When I run the code it shows the 2k-ish rows that are stored in the rawName.range and then for each strName sheet shows 1048576 rows, instead of the 800 or 300, or 20 rows that each different sheet has.

File is attached for a little more in depth approach
Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/10rXA6fInX5g8zJucrnxsNHl-7vXBpIvz/view?usp=sharing[/link]